# Formatting into text file in R

Tags: r, text, dataformat

I have a quick formatting question. I have a set of data in a data frame that looks like this:

```
Animal   Food   Food ID
 dog     steak   100
 dog     beef    200
 dog     poo     001
 cat     milk    020
 cat     steak   100
 cat     beef    200
```

which, for programming input purposes, I need to transform into a '.txt' file with a format like this :

```
<dog>
steak   100
beef    200
poo     001
</dog>

<cat>     
milk    020
steak   100
beef    200
</cat>
```

Obviously my real data has tens of thousands of entries or else I could do it by hand. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
# create the string
text <- paste0(sapply(unique(dat$Animal), function(x) {
  subdat <- dat[dat$Animal == x, -1]
  subdat[[2]] <- sprintf("%03d", subdat[[2]])
  paste0("<", x, ">\n",
         paste(capture.output(write.table(subdat, sep = "\t",
                                          quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, 
                                          col.names = FALSE)), collapse = "\n"),
         "\n</", x, ">")
}), collapse = "\n\n")

# write it to a file
write(text, file = "filename.txt")
```

The resulting file:

```
<dog>
steak   100
beef    200
poo 001
</dog>

<cat>
milk    020
steak   100
beef    200
</cat>
```

The columns are tab-delimited.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses the `d_ply` function to separate the animals before processing.  Notice the default delimited (of a space) can be changed.

Will records ever need to be collapsed?  For instance, if `dog` has two rows for `steak`, should they be combined in some way?  If so, the plyr approach should be able to accommodate that, with a little modification.

```
ProcessAnimal <- function( d, fileLocation, delimiter=" " ) {
  cat(paste0("<", d$Animal[1], ">\n"), file=fileLocation, append=TRUE, sep="")

  cat(sapply(seq_len(nrow(ds)), function(i) {
    paste0(paste0(ds[i, c("Food", "FoodID")], collapse=delimiter), sep="\n")
  }), file=fileLocation, append=TRUE, sep="")

  cat(paste0("</", d$Animal[1], ">\n"), file=fileLocation, append=TRUE, sep="")
}

plyr::d_ply(.data=ds, .variables="Animal", .fun=ProcessAnimal, fileLocation="PetFood.txt")
```

The text file looks like:

```
<cat>
steak 100
beef 200
poo 001
milk 020
steak 100
beef 200
</cat>
<dog>
steak 100
beef 200
poo 001
milk 020
steak 100
beef 200
</dog>
```